# Git: Android Studio "--ff-only" merge option is greyed out

Tags: git, android-studio, merge, fast-forward

I'm working on an Android java app and just finished a feature called "addmypicture" that I need to merge with "Master".

I'd like to keep track of history so, as far as I know, the option I should use for merging is --ff-only, but for any reason it appears greyed out in Android Studio, and the only option is to do "--no-ff".

Haven't tried using the console because this is a big feature and I feel more comfortable doing it through the GUI.

My question is how to un-grey out "--ff-only" option and if, given my requirements of keeping history, is the recommended option to go.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check first if the merge would be fast-forward anyway, meaning check if the history is

```
m--m--m         (master)
       \
        f--f--f (feature/addmypicture)
```

Use `git log --graph --oneline --decorate` from your current branch.

If the merge is a fast-forward one, that could explain why --ff-only is grayed, considered the merge is in this case by default fast-forward.

Comment: Thank you very much @VonC. I've run your given git bash command and what I see is addmypicture (with all its commits) is on top and in the exact same timeline than master, which is just below (with all its commits too). According to what you say, I can guess I'm in a fast forward so if I uncheck "--no-ff" it will be the default setting, right? If so I'll mark your answer as correct :) (Maybe Android Studio is detecting that fast forward can be done and it's marking it as default automatically?) (Something new I've learnt)

Comment: @DiegoPerez That would be my supposition. It only allows you to check options which are not already in effect.